# trouble couting an integer got through pointers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I was trying to cout the value of a int variable from another cpp of the same project (visual studio c++) using a pointer, instead of the integer it is showing certain Alphabets
"CDCDCDCD" 
The address of the variable is displayed correctly . Can any one suggest be what would be the problem.

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see. Probably, you're just missing a `*`.

Answer (score 0):

The "alphabets" is hexadecimal. CDCD... indicates that it has not been initialises for VS

Please supply some code for a better answer

Comment: Why CD? That is a philosophical question between Bill and Old Harry